# Animated space movie with an all-women crew who are killed except for one who has a son

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

It is an old animated movie;  I watched it on videotape around 1999-2002.

I remember that the action is in space, the crew members are women. At the end of the movie, there are only two left alive, mother and son, who grew up overnight because of the planet they were on. When I asked the question before on another portal, a man claims that he remembers that there was also a bomb that threatens the entire universe. Unfortunately, he doesn't remember the name of the movie either.

Answer (score 12):

You may be thinking of ***[Gall Force: Eternal Story](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0158628/)*** (1986). It's the first film in a [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall_Force).

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/GallForce):

> *Gall Force* is a group of science fiction anime OAV series made starting in 1986 by the studio Artmic, with production by Youmex and AIC.
>
> The original series concerns a Hopeless War between the One-Gender Race of Solnoids (humanoid females) and the Paranoids, who are an amorphous race that usually inhabits powered armor suits. The remaining crew of the Solnoid cruiser Star Leaf barely escape the destruction of their fleet in yet another hopeless battle, only to get caught up in a conspiracy that will have far reaching consequences for all concerned.

- The story involves a spaceship called the Star Leaf, which is manned by an all-female crew.
- One of the crew members gives birth to a baby boy who matures at an accelerated rate.
- At the end, the only two survivors are the boy (now a young man) and one of the women (not the mother).

You can view a scene with some the female crew members discussing the baby's abnormal growth rate at around the 1:02:22 mark in the video below.

Comment: Thank you. That's the movie

Comment: @Coa - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].